# How to remove an image maps colored border using HTML and CSS3

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a style rule for inline images that contain the usemap attribute and set the border around this image to 0 pixels.

I've tried:

```
#locks {border: 0px;}
```

Here is my image map:

```
<img src="locks.jpg" alt="lock links" width="510" height="110" usemap="#locks" />

<map name="locks">
...
</map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img usemap="locks">
...
</map>

img[usemap=locks] {
    border: none;
}
```

[Attribute Selectors - W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors)

Comment: I'd like to create a style rule for inline images using the usemap attribute.

Comment: Almost there, you mean `img[usemap]`. You went too specific for what the topic starter requested :-) +1 none the less.(and you should also just do `border: 0;`)

Comment: You don't need px after 0. 0 is just 0.

Answer (score 0):

Add id or class to

```
<map id="locks">

#locks {
    border: 0;
}
```

or

```
<map class="locks">

.locks {
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to create a style rule for inline images using the usemap attribute.

Answer (score 0):

well you are mixing up two things

lock is name of the map.

Try using

Create a different css class and use it in map or image tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently taking a class and this question is part of my assignment.  The correct answer is:

```
img[usemap] {
  border: 0px;
}
```

There is a section on pg. 169 of the book (HTML and CSS, 6th edition) that covers attribute selectors.  This would be the 4th selector example down the list.